# Blood type frequency given probability

Tags: genetics

I have calculated the probability that any child will have a particular blood type from both the genotype level and the phenotype level assuming the human ABO Rh system is followed.

Here are the genotype probabilities:

```
AA+/+ 49/1764
AA+/- 98/1764
AA-/- 49/1764
AO+/+ 98/1764
AO+/- 196/1764
AO-/- 98/1764
BB+/+ 49/1764
BB+/- 98/1764
BB-/- 49/1764
BO+/+ 98/1764
BO+/- 196/1764
BO-/- 98/1764
AB+/+ 98/1764
AB+/- 196/1764
AB-/- 98/1764
OO+/+ 49/1764
OO+/- 98/1764
OO-/- 49/1764
```

Here are the phenotype probabilities:

```
A+ 441/1764
A- 147/1764
B+ 441/1764
B- 147/1764
AB+ 294/1764
AB- 98/1764
O+ 147/1764
O- 49/1764
```

Here is the frequency of the blood types in the 1st generation by genotype:

```
AA+/+ 5/101
AA+/- 5/101
AA-/- 5/101
BB+/+ 5/101
BB+/- 5/101
BB-/- 5/101
AB+/+ 5/101
AB+/- 10/101
AB-/- 5/101
OO+/+ 5/101
OO+/- 5/101
OO-/- 5/101
AO+/- 10/101
AO+/+ 5/101
AO-/- 5/101
BO+/+ 4/101
BO+/- 4/101
BO-/- 4/101
```

Here are the numbers and their genders; a number represents an individual from a population of 101:

```
Male: 
0,2,5,10,11,17,20,22,23,31,34,40,41,44,46,47,50,55,59,61,62,68,71,79,80,82,85,88,89,92,94,100

Hermaphroditic(and fertile):
4,8,16,25,32,64
```

all the rest are female

M/F mating: 11,904 offspring in 2nd generation H/A mating(hermaphrodites can mate with other hermaphrodites, males, females, and even themselves): 3636 offspring in 2nd generation

If you divide these by 6 you will get the amount per operation. The operations I am taking into consideration are +, -, *, /, ^, nth root, and arrow arrow(tetration).

So how can I take the frequency of blood types at the genotype level, probability of blood type at genotype and phenotype levels, and total number of offspring to get a 1st order estimate of the frequency of these blood types in the 2nd generation?

Comment: This question is *very* hard to read, I suggest that if you put some effort in to the formatting you'll more likely get a good answer :)

Comment: "Here are the numbers and their genders:" ... what do you mean here?

Comment: Since this biological data is from my Math World story numbers such as 0 and 100 have genders. Their gender is determined by 4 sex chromosomes. XXXX = female, XXXY = male, XXYY = hermaphroditic, and XYYY = male

Comment: So you mean there is 32(?) males, 6 hermaphrodites, and 101-(32+6) females??

Comment: yes that is what I mean

Comment: *"The operations I am taking into consideration are +, -, *, /, ^, nth root, and arrow arrow(tetration)."*: This part is also unclear

Comment: In math world the eggs and sperm have these operational chromosomes. For arithmetic they are +, -, *, /, ^,nth root, and arrow arrow(tetration). Different combinations of egg and first sperm to fertilize it lead to different operations done with the numerical value of the mother and the father. The mother is always the first addend, first factor, dividend, minuend, base, index, or is an exponent and a base in the case of tetration(which is repeated exponentiation).